# Implementing a FAB button to the left of the header and hanging part below it

Tags: css, material-design-lite

Trying to implement an Add Button to the left of my header in MDL.

An Example can be seen on the getmdl.io site here https://getmdl.io/templates/text-only/index.html

I have the following header defined.

```
    <header class="mdl-layout__header">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
            <span class="mdl-layout-title">Task Manager</span>
            <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable">
                <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="search-expandable">
                    <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                </label>
                <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="search-expandable" />
                    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="search-expandable">Search text</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored mdl-shadow--4dp mdl-color--accent mdl-button--mini-fab mdl-badge--overlap" id="add">
            <i class="material-icons" role="presentation">add</i>
            <span class="visuallyhidden">Add</span>
        </button>
    </header>
```

There is no need for tabs in this project - but cannot seem to get it to drop part below the header as in the example linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS to the stylesheet linked to the page

```
.mdl-layout__header
{
    position: relative;
    overflow:visible;
}

.add-button{
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: -25px;
}
```

Then add the following class to the button

```
add-button
```